# Why Shopware 6 uses deep link codes?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Does someone know why Shopware 6 uses deep link codes in URLs for some resources? For example in the document route `/_action/document/{documentId}/{deepLinkCode}`. Why not just use the `documentId`, it is unique. Is it for better security?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is just for added security. If a document ID gets compromised, potential attackers would still need to obtain the corresponding `deepLinkCode` to open the document.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Dominic's answer:

In essence it is user (documentId) and password (deepLinkCode). The user can be known, but the password should be kept a secret.